# get first object in mongoengine

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, mongoengine

I have a class with name of `Request` and I want to get first object of it in mongoengine 
I think I can use this :

first get all objects like this
 `visitors = Request.objects.all()`
and then 
 `ss = visitors[0].ip`
and then call an attribute of object

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's simple just use :
`Request.objects.first()`